# clojure swap with arbitrary return value

Tags: concurrency, clojure, clojurescript

Is there a way to `swap!` and return an arbitrary value along with the value of the `atom`?

For instance:

```
(swap! (atom {1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 5 5})
         (fn [m]
           (loop []
             (let [i (rand-int 10)]
               (if (contains? m i)
                 (recur)
                 (assoc m i "ok"))))))
```

In the above function I have no way to know which key was added to the map (unless I list them beforehand).

I could use another atom to store the result, but it there something simpler I am overlooking?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a weird but general approach:

```
(defn swap-diff! [atom f & args]
  (loop []
    (let [curr-value @atom
          new-value (apply f curr-value args)]
      (if (compare-and-set! atom curr-value new-value)
        [new-value (data/diff curr-value new-value)]
        (recur)))))
```

This uses `compare-and-set!` in a `loop` until it succeeds, similar to [how `swap!` works internally](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/1215ba346ffea3fe48def6ec70542e3300b6f9ed/src/jvm/clojure/lang/Atom.java#L33-L45). When it succeeds, it returns a tuple of the new value and the output of `clojure.data/diff`. The `diff` output will show you exactly how the atom's value changed.

```
(swap-diff! (atom {1 1, 2 2, 3 3})
            #(loop []
               (let [i (rand-int 10)]
                 (if (contains? % i)
                   (recur)
                   (assoc % i "ok")))))
=> [{1 1, 2 2, 3 3, 9 "ok"} (nil {9 "ok"} {3 3, 2 2, 1 1})]
```

`{1 1, 2 2, 3 3, 9 "ok"}` is the atom's new value. `(nil {9 "ok"} {3 3, 2 2, 1 1})` is the output of `diff`, where the first item are items *only* in the old value, the second item are items *only* on the new value, and the third value are items in *both*. In your case, you only care about the new items.

Update: If you don't want to deal with a tuple return value, you could tag the return value with diff metadata:

```
(defn swap-diff! [atom f & args]
  (loop []
    (let [curr-value @atom
          new-value (apply f curr-value args)]
      (if (compare-and-set! atom curr-value new-value)
          (with-meta new-value
                     (zipmap [:before :after :both]
                             (data/diff curr-value new-value)))
        (recur)))))
```

And then call `meta` on the result to get the diff:

```
(meta *1)
=> {:before nil, :after {9 "ok"}, :both {3 3, 2 2, 1 1}}
```

### Clojure 1.9

This becomes much cleaner with a new function `swap-vals!`:

```
(defn swap-diff! [atom f & args]
  (let [[old new] (apply swap-vals! atom f args)]
    (with-meta new (zipmap [:before :after :both]
                           (data/diff old new)))))
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to just put both the return value and the result in a map:

```
(swap! (atom {:value {1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 5 5}
              :return nil})
       (fn [{:keys [value]}]
           (loop []
             (let [i (rand-int 10)]
               (if (contains? value i)
                 (recur)
                 {:value (assoc value i "ok")
                  :return i})))))
```

Note that your example function is not a pure function (because it uses `rand-int`), so it is not a correct usage of `swap!`

Comment: aha I was suspecting something like that about `rand-int`. Maybe the whole problem has to be rethought. It is not desirable to alter the shape of the existing `atom` though.

Comment: alternatives approaches are putting the return value in metadata via `with-meta`, or define a volatile box in a let binding and set it to the value to return with `vreset!`